# Records Not showing in template

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I am running this with Python 2.7.2 and Django 1.4.1 on Windows 7.

I have several records in the sqlite db and I am trying to get them displayed using generic class views ListView.  I have eliminated things that it couldn't be and stripped everything to the simplest possible format but I am not sure where to go to figure out what it could be.

Model:

```
class DMG_New_Inv (models.Model): # DMG's
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DMG_New_Inv, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.objects = None

model_num = models.ForeignKey(DMG_Models_Default, verbose_name='Model')
serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Serial Number')
date_in = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) #this will set the date to the creation date automaticly
date_out = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True) # the date is was removed from inventory
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name='Asset Status', choices=DMG_ASSET_STATUS) # see list above
company = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Company', blank=True, null=True) # the company or person who received the product
notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Notes',  blank=True, null=True)
pass
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'DMG'
    verbose_name_plural = 'DMGs'
```

View:

```
from django.views.generic import list
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from inventory.models import DMG_New_Inv

class dmg_new_status(ListView):

context_object_name = "dmg_new_status"
template_name = 'inventory/dmg_inv.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    status = get_object_or_404(DMG_New_Inv, status__iexact=self.args[0])
    return DMG_New_Inv.objects.filter(status__iexact=status)
```

Content:

```
{% block content %}

<div id="content">

<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
    <tr align="center">
        <th>Model</th><th>Serial Number</th><th>Date In</th><th>Date Out</th><th>Status</th><th>Company</th><th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    {% for dmg in dmg_new_status %}

    <tr align="center">
        <td>{{ dmg.model_num }}</td>
        <td>{{ dmg.serial_num }}</td>
        <td>{{ dmg.date_in }}</td>
        <td>{{ dmg.date_out }}</td>
        <td>{{ dmg.status }}</td>
        <td> {{ dmg.company }}</td>
        <td> {{ dmg.notes }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    No DMG's in this list
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

{% endblock %}

URL:

```
(r'^inventory/dmg/(\w+)/$', dmg_new_status.as_view()), #status page
```

I am certain it is not a path issue as I added the empty option and it displays the table headers but no records.  If I had to guess and I am guessing, I am not returning anything and therefore the array is empty.  I am not sure how to troubleshoot this any further.  I opened a console imported everything and ran the query_set function that way and got nothing, which is why I believe the error is in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a problem in get_queryset(self) ...
The first line gets a DMG_New_Inv object but you assign it to the variable status.

Shouldn't the last line be something like ...

```
return DMG_New_Inv.objects.filter(status__iexact=status.status)
```

(You also might want to use a different variable than "status")